# Where does "Encode Selected Video Files" live in mac Mojave?

Tags: macos, video, encode, finder

I would like to access the workflow in Mac Mojave ("Encode Selected Video Files") to be able to repair it. At the moment I can't find it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the Automator action, that would be at **/System/Library/Automator/Encode Media.action**.  Note that you shouldn't mess with anything in the System folder (Mojave most likely wont let you anyway), any editing should be made on a copy.

Depending on what you are "repairing", you could just call the **avconvert** command line utility yourself, since that is pretty much all the action does.

Comment: Thanks, red_menace. I am talking about the action that pops in the menu when one right clicks a video file. The action or rather "workflow" is called "Encode Selected Video Files", and I think it's not just an action, but a workflow. The issue is that it's not working well, because after updating to MOJAVE everytime I use this on a video, it creates a  static video (one frame on view, audio fine). That is why I wanted to access the workflow to check what was wrong, although it could be that there is a codec problem and I should update my video codecs (not sure how).PS: What is avconvert?

Comment: The "Encode Selected Video Files" workflow is embedded in the referenced "Encode Media" Automator action bundle (the action itself is AppleScript based).  avconvert is a command line utility - from the Terminal, use  **avconvert -h**  (help text) or  **man avconvert**  (manual page) for information.

Comment: Thanks, I will  have a look at avconver (I hope it can do batch jobs, because I need to encode many video files at a time).

Comment: As for the "Encode Selected Video Files" workflow, I can't see how I can access it. When I open the action "Encode Media", I can't see this workflow...

Comment: Right-click on **Encode Media.action** and "Show Package Contents" - the workflow is in the **Contents/Resources** folder, but what you are wanting to edit is **Encode_Media.scpt**, which is a regular AppleScript file (the action code) that the workflow uses.